# Which stack exchange site is best to ask a question about compiling the Octave application?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

I am looking for assistance in changing the options to either the `make` or `./configure` so I can compile [Gnu Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/index.html) without debug symbols and save some space. (I am using the current Ubuntu release if that matters).

I did a search of all Stack Exchange sites and it appears that in the past questions about Octave have been asked on Stack Overflow. However, I am afraid that if I ask my question there I will be zapped with the dreaded "*This is **not** a question about programming*" feedback.

What is the appropriate Stack Exchange venue to ask questions about how to compile/build an open source application such as Octave?

Comment: [su] / [unix.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions on building / compiling will go well on either [Super User](http://superuser.com) / [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Ubuntu Stack Exchange](http://askubuntu.com)